# Convert numeric time in milliseconds to datetime with seconds with decimal value

Tags: r, datetime, lubridate

How to convert numeric time in milliseconds to `datetime` format with seconds with decimal values (preferably using `lubridate`?

```
time = 1633708877772
```

Comment: what is the expected value?  Do you need `as_datetime(time/1000)`

Comment: as_datetime(time/1000) = "2021-10-08 16:01:17 UTC" I was expecting seconds up to three decimal places.

Comment: You can format to show the milliseconds i.e. `strftime(as_datetime(time/1000), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS3')
[1] "2021-10-08 11:01:17.772"`

Comment: Thanks, that should work. Is there a simple solution without using lubridate

Comment: I posted a solution with `as.POSIXct` from `base R`.  thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `lubridate`, using `as_datetime`

```
library(lubridate)
as_datetime(time/1000)
[1] "2021-10-08 16:01:17 UTC"
```

Note that the milliseconds are not `print`ed in the console.  If we need to print, then format with `strftime` or `format` (but it will not be a datetime object anymore)

```
strftime(as_datetime(time/1000), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS3') 
#[1] "2021-10-08 11:01:17.772"
```

---

Or without using any package, just specify it in `as.POSIXct`

```
as.POSIXct(time/1000, origin = '1970-01-01')
[1] "2021-10-08 11:01:17 CDT"
```